# back/forward buttons don't show up in xev (pcmanfm doesn't work)

Tags: logitech, pcmanfm, xev

`xinput test 9` results in the buttons being identified as 8 and 9.

However, the results in `xev` are the following:

```
LeaveNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0xa2, subw 0x0, time 780795, (17,2), root:(18,94),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

EnterNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0xa2, subw 0x0, time 780970, (17,2), root:(18,94),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967202 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This presumably results in a failure to xbindkey to said buttons (as an attempted solution to) and failure in pcmanfm.

As per the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

/etc/X11/xorg.conf did not exist

I set /etc/X11/xorg.conf to:

```
Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier      "Logitech"
        Driver          "evdev"
        Option          "Name" "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"
EndSection
InputDevice     "Logitech" "CorePointer"
```

However, this caused the operating system to fail identifying devices forcing a rollback to this configuration.

1. How does one facilitate production of a button event in `xev` in these circumstances?
2. If there is no facilitation of #1 or if one is irrelevant to the following, how does one get back and forward buttons working in pcmanfm?

Answer (score 1):

My bad I didn't have `xvkbd` installed. I installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install xvkbd
```

However, `xev` of course still has the specified output so an explanation as to its correctness would be valuable.